# Tick mark on pre-populated tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that has been created like this in XCODE (no code).

[image]

I am trying to get a tick on the right hand side when either one of the rows is pressed, I am using IOS7.

This is causing a bit of nightmare. Here is so code I am implementing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell new];


    cell.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(cell.selected){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }else{
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    }


}
```

Comment: You appear to be creating a new cell when a row is selected.  Do you think that is correct?

Comment: You have to store selected cell state locally and then check it's state in cellForRowAtIndexPath, that it was previously selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];


    cell.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(cell.selected){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }else{
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    }


}
```